# Carousal - auto height in collapsed div (GlideJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using [GlideJS](http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/) to display a carousal. The height of each item in this carousal is different and I have therefore set the property:

```
autoheight: true
```

The problem is when I try to display the carousal in a collapsed div with the autoheight property set to 'true' the carousal is not displayed. When the autoheight property is set to false the carousal does display but then the height of the items is fixed. To illustrate this problem I have created the following Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7dma7L84/21/

How can I display the carousal in a collapsed div with auto height for each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is not what you looking to be?]

Check this picture and please confirm me if I understand correctly your desired

Comment: Yes that looks great. I can't seem to reproduce your result, is it possible for you to share your Fiddle?

Comment: The problem is: I change indeed the carousel height to auto, but the browser don't render again the dom. To demonstrate this: 1. #Carousel { height: auto; }, 2. open browser console and your carousel is displayed. So, you must solve this with a callback function for your toggle content. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I play a little with this and seems to solve problem with this:

```
#Carousel {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
var carousel = $('#Carousel').glide({
    type: 'carousel',
    startAt: 1,
    touchDistance: 2,
    autoplay: 0,
    autoheight: true
});
```

What do you think?

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve the problem when I update the Fiddle with your code :( Do you perhaps have a working example?

Comment: `autoheight` doesn't exist.